# Creating multiple private chat session using SignalR in an .ascx ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, signalr

SignalR is really testing me.  I'm using vs2010.

I've looked over about 30 samples, and I'm unable to even create a simple SignalR chat.  What I have is a a simple asp.net page, that loads a couple .ascxs.  Inside of one of those .ascx's I just want to load a SignalR chat.  If anybody knows an exact sample of this, I would be deeply grateful.

In most signalR samples I get this far.

Install SignalR NuGet
Then add my Chat and ChatHub Classes.

After this i'm at a loss.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the SignalR sample chat from **https://github.com/SignalR/Samples** and run it on Visual Studio 2012, it worked out for me.

I think you must install Visual Studio 2012 so that the references and packages that come with it are compatible.

Comment: Hasan i'll give it a go

Comment: Hasan - yep all i just is the textbox and the send button, i click on it nothin ghappens

Comment: Hasan, yes I installed all dependancies.  the same works, its when places inside of ascx everything stops working

Comment: @Mike check my update. I tested it and it worked for me. You might need to install Visual Studio 2012 to run the github chat sample because there might be compatibility issues, and make sure there is no error on the dependencies (references) in solution explorer.